# Clear the history when user logout form Application In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS, I am working on web based project using AngularJS.

When the user logs out of the application or when user clicks the browser back button application is going to previous page.

Can anyone show me how to restrict the back button after user logout?

I tried

```
$location.replace();
```

And I tried

```
Window.history.forward();
```

But I am not able to work it out. Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Comment: You can't control the user's back button. You have some control over history, but it's probably not what you want. Why do you not want the user to go back after logout?

Comment: Hi Kevin, My Problem is once user logout form Application, If suppose he trying to click the back button, My application is going to pervious page, I want restrict that, Do you have any idea can u pls share thanks

Comment: You want to end the session when the user logs out, and in your app handle an unauthenticated session by redirecting to the login page.

Comment: Hi @KevinBoucher, If don't feel, can u pls explain me how can i achieve the solution please.

Comment: I'm sure there are some tutorials. If you log the user out correctly, they wo'nt be able to go back to the website.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: you can't control the browser history.

Comment: Hi @Pierre, There is no solution for this one?